# Having issues iterating through machine code

Tags: c, bash

I'm attempting to recreate the wc command in c and having issues getting the proper number of words in any file containing machine code (core files or compiled c). The number of logged words always comes up around 90% short of the amount returned by wc.

For reference here is the project info

Compile statement

```
gcc -ggdb wordCount.c -o wordCount -std=c99
```

wordCount.c

```
/*
 *  Author(s)   - Colin McGrath
 *  Description - Lab 3 - WC LINUX
 *  Date        - January 28, 2015
 */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct counterStruct {
    int newlines;
    int words;
    int bt;
};

typedef struct counterStruct ct;

ct totals = {0};

struct stat st;

void wc(ct counter, char *arg)
{
    printf("%6lu %6lu %6lu %s\n", counter.newlines, counter.words, counter.bt, arg);
}

void process(char *arg)
{
    lstat(arg, &st);
    if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
    {
        char message[4056] = "wc: ";
        strcat(message, arg);
        strcat(message, ": Is a directory\n");
        printf(message);
        ct counter = {0};
        wc(counter, arg);
    }
    else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
    {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(arg, "r");
        ct currentCount = {0};
        if (file != NULL)
        {
            char holder[65536];
            while (fgets(holder, 65536, file) != NULL)
            {
                totals.newlines++;
                currentCount.newlines++;
                int c = 0;
                for (int i=0; i<strlen(holder); i++)
                {
                    if (isspace(holder[i]))
                    {
                        if (c != 0)
                        {
                            totals.words++;
                            currentCount.words++;
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        c = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        currentCount.bt = st.st_size;
        totals.bt = totals.bt + st.st_size;
        wc(currentCount, arg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        {
            //printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
            process(argv[i]);
        }
    }

    wc(totals, "total");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample wc output:

```
    135     742  360448 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/core.22321
    231    1189  192512 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/core.26554
   5372   40960  365441 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/file
     24     224   12494 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/frequency
     45     116     869 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/frequency.c
   5372   40960  365441 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/lineIn
     12      50    1013 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/lineIn2
      0       0       0 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/lineOut
     39     247   11225 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/parseURL
    138     318    2151 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/parseURL.c
     41     230   10942 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/roman
     66     162    1164 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/roman.c
     13      13      83 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/romanIn
     13      39     169 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/romanOut
      7       6     287 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/URLs
  11508   85256 1324239 total
```

Sample rebuild output (./wordCount):

```
   139     76 360448 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/core.22321
   233    493 192512 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/core.26554
  5372  40960 365441 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/file
    25      3  12494 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/frequency
    45    116    869 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/frequency.c
  5372  40960 365441 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/lineIn
    12     50   1013 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/lineIn2
     0      0      0 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/lineOut
    40      6  11225 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/parseURL
   138    318   2151 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/parseURL.c
    42      3  10942 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/roman
    66    162   1164 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/roman.c
    13     13     83 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/romanIn
    13     39    169 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/romanOut
     7      6    287 /home/cpmcgrat/53/labs/lab-2/URLs
 11517  83205 1324239 total
```

Notice the difference in the word count (second int) from the first two files (core files) as well as the roman file and parseURL files (machine code, no extension).

Comment: What does `file core.22321` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C strings do not store their length. They are terminated by a single `NUL` (0) byte.

Consequently, `strlen` needs to scan the entire string, character by character, until it reaches the `NUL`. That makes this:

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(holder); i++)
```

desperately inefficient: for every character in `holder`, it needs to count all the characters in `holder` in order to test whether `i` is still in range. That transforms a simple linear `Θ(N)` algorithm into an `Θ(N2)` cycle-burner.

But in this case, it also produces the wrong result, since binary files typically include lots of `NUL` characters. Since `strlen` will actually tell you where the first `NUL` is, rather than how long the "line" is, you'll end up skipping a lot of bytes in the file. (On the bright side, that makes the scan quadratically faster, but computing the wrong result more rapidly is not really a win.)

You cannot use `fgets` to read binary files because the `fgets` interface doesn't tell you how much it read. You can use the Posix 2008 `getline` interface instead, or you can do binary input with `fread`, which is more efficient but will force you to count newlines yourself. (Not the worst thing in the world; you seem to be getting that count wrong, too.)

Or, of course, you could read the file one character at a time with `fgetc`. For a school exercise, that's not a bad solution; the resulting code is easy to write and understand, and typical implementations of `fgetc` are more efficient than the FUD would indicate.

Comment: Once upon an internet aeon or so ago (late 80's, very early 90's; almost before there was an internet), I ran into a bug with SunOS `strstr()` which contained a `strlen()` in the loop condition.  It worked OK on toy stuff, but when I started working it with 20 KiB buffers, the performance of the program fell apart.  I ended up using a custom implementation of `strstr()` on SunOS; the HP-UX machine the customer used didn't have a problem -- and neither, I hasten to add, did most subsequent versions of SunOS.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: A really clever compiler might optimize the strlen call, but it would have to be really clever to do that when the argument is not declared `const`. Rather more recently, I managed to enormously improve the performance of a critical function whose author thought that `str::find(word) == 0` was the normal idiom for checking whether `str` starts with `word` (another conceivable optimization). Optimization is important, but education is *more* important.